# jqVmap Static Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jqvmap

So I know how to make a custom tooltip using jqvmap's documentation, but I'm trying to look for a way I could hover over a region and the tooltip stay in its hover state so long as I am in the region. Not move as I move the mouse.

Just for reference here is jqVmap's site: http://jqvmap.com/

The idea is I want each state to have a button I can click to go to it's page, but the tooltip always moves as you move with the region and I want to stop it from doing so.

Any suggestions?

You can see the example on this site: (The non working example and why its a problem): http://111project.org.s159009.gridserver.com/

I can basically control everything but the position and movement of the tooltip.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in http://111project.org/wp-content/themes/111/js/main.js you will find the code that triggers the box.

```
onRegionOver: function (event, code, region) {
        var state_abbr = code;
        var state = $(region);
        var id = '#jqvmap1_' + state_abbr;
        var offset = $(id).offset();
        var left_offset = offset.left;
        var top_offset = offset.top;
        console.log(left_offset);

        // if (code == 'ok' || code ==  'fl' || code == 'ga') {
        if (code == 'ok' || code == 'ga' || code == 'fl') {

          $('#state_tooltip').css({
            'left': left_offset - 120,
            'top': top_offset - 100,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'block',
            'opacity': 1
          });

          var new_url = region.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');

          $('#state_tooltip h5').text(region);

          $('#state_tooltip .button').attr('href', new_url);

          if (code == 'ok') {
            $('#state_tooltip p').html('115 commited <br> Families');
          }

          if (code == 'ga') {
            $('#state_tooltip p').html('20 commited <br> Families');
          }

          if (code == 'fl') {
            $('#state_tooltip p').html('24 commited <br> Families');
          }

        }


    },
    onRegionOut: function (element, code, region) {
      console.log('out');
        $('#state_tooltip h5').text();
    }
```

You can then copy the code in the HTML for #state_tooltip

```
<div id="state_tooltip" style="display: none;">
<h5></h5>
<p>20 Committed <br> Families</p>
<a class="button" href="">Learn More</a>
```

You can find the CSS for #state_tooltip in the CSS file. http://111project.org/wp-content/themes/111/style.css

```
#state_tooltip {
    text - align: left;
    - webkit - border - radius: 5px;
    - moz - border - radius: 5px;
    - ms - border - radius: 5px;
    - o - border - radius: 5px;
    border - radius: 5px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #1293b9;
    font-size:smaller;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out, 1s;
    -moz-transition:all ease-in-out, 1s;
    -o-transition:all ease-in-out, 1s;
    transition:all ease-in-out, 1s;
    opacity:0
}
#state_tooltip h5 {
    color: #0c5165;
    font-size:1.375em;
    font-weight:normal
}
#state_tooltip.button {
    font - size: 0.9375em;
    padding: 5px 10px
}
```

**BTW Thank you for making this stack overflow question. Without it I would not have been able to customize the tooltips on tooltips on jqvmap so easily to have multi line tooltips on a project I am working on.**

Comment: Not a problem. Answered months later haha. So weird, but glad you got help out of it :)